# Write code automatically in php js

Tags: javascript, php

I just begin learn php and js, and have difficulty how to write code like below. I have 5 checkboxes, when i check all, sql insert add 5 values like below. I mean, how to write it dynamically in sql insert section, when i choose only one, or 2, or some, and even all. That way, I do not have to write

```
    ('$idkeg',01, '$kabkot'),
    ('$idkeg',02, '$kabkot'),
    ('$idkeg',03, '$kabkot'),
    ('$idkeg',04, '$kabkot'),
    ('$idkeg',05, '$kabkot')
```

one by one

Full codes:

```
<label><input type='checkbox' name="all" id="all" value='all'>Seluruh kab/kota</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' value='01'>Sibolga</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' value='02'>Tanjung Balai</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' value='03'>Pematang Siantar</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' value='04'>Tebing Tinggi</label>
<label><input type='checkbox' value='05'>Medan</label>

mysqli_query($koneksi, "INSERT INTO event(idkeg,kdwil,kabkot) VALUES 
('$idkeg',01, '$kabkot'),
('$idkeg',02, '$kabkot'),
('$idkeg',03, '$kabkot'),
('$idkeg',04, '$kabkot'),
('$idkeg',05, '$kabkot')
;") or die(mysqli_error());
```

Comment: So you want to insert a different number of value-pairs everytime? E.g. checkboxes 1, 2 and 5 in one run, then only 2 and 5 ansd so on?

Comment: you have to use loop for it.

Comment: @TobiasF. no, say i just check some checkbox, and insert it to sql

Comment: So you want to have a live-update everytime you check or uncheck a single checkbox or do you want only the values to be added which are checked when you hit the submit button?

Comment: Yap @TobiasF. wanna only the values to be added which are checked when hit the submit. any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give same array name to each check box, then after form submit it will give you values of selected check boxes in array

eg.

```
 <input type='checkbox' name="arrayName[]" value='05'>Medan</label>
```

output of `$_POST['arrayName']` will be `['02','03','05']`

then perform INSERT Operation in Loop

```
$checkedArray = $_POST['arrayName'];

foreach($checkedArray as $checked){
  $query = "INSERT INTO event(idkeg,kdwil,kabkot) VALUES('$idkeg','$checked','$kabkot')";
  mysqli_query($koneksi, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: I would recommend to run the query outside of the loop and concatenate the results afterwars, so you only have to execute one query, and not multiple.

Comment: @Zaheer Altar you should fix the typo within your answer, replace the first `'` after `$query` with `"`.

Comment: thanks @TobiasF. for typo. Your approach is also good for optimization purpose.

Comment: But what if my value is "'; DROP DATABASE..."? At least use escaping.